# Failed to add image. Got error: openstack glance

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04, openstack

Following glance command to add image is failing

```
glance  add name="CirrOS 0.3.1" disk-format=qcow2 container-format=bare is-public=true < cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img
```

and the error recieved

```
Uploading image 'CirrOS 0.3.1'
=============================================================[100%] 5.68M/s, ETA  0h  0m  0s
Failed to add image. Got error:
Data supplied was not valid.
Details: 400 Bad Request

The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.

 Failed to activate image. Got error: Data supplied was not valid. Details: 400 Bad Request  The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.   Failed to update image metadata. Got error: Data supplied was not valid. Details: Invalid disk format 'None' for image.    
Note: Your image metadata may still be in the registry, but the image's status will likely be 'killed'.
```

Not sure which argument went wrong any help appreciated

this is my file

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/images$ file cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img 
cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img: QEMU QCOW Image (v2), 41126400 bytes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these options should work:

The command argument names should use underscores (`_`) instead of dashes (`-`):

```
glance add name="CirrOS 0.3.1" disk_format=qcow2 container_format=bare is_public=true < cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img
```

Alternatively it might be that the command arguments need to be prefixed with `--`:

```
glance add --name="CirrOS 0.3.1" --disk-format=qcow2 --container-format=bare --is-public=true < cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img
```

Comment: glance add name="CirrOS 0.3.1" disk_format=qcow2 container_format=bare is_public=true < cirros-0.3.1-x86_64-disk.img
Uploading image 'CirrOS 0.3.1'
=============================================================[100%] 5.97M/s, ETA  0h  0m  0s
Added new image with ID: 5026478e-f4a3-49f8-9096-438ebcbfd721